# When to use Big O instead of theta or little o

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, little-o

A question about asymptotic notation. I've seen a lot of explanations of asymptotic notation say:

`θ(...)` is analogous to `=`

`O(...)` is analogous to `<=`

`o(...)` is analogous to `<`

Which would seem to imply that if `f(n) = O(g(n))`, then either `f(n) = θ(g(n))` or `f(n) = o(g(n))`.

Is it possible to have `f(n) = O(g(n))` such that neither `f(n) = θ(g(n))` nor `f(n) = o(g(n))`? If so, what is an example of this? And if not, then why would we ever use `O(...)` when `θ(...)` or `o(...)` are stronger descriptors?

Comment: "analogous" in this case is far from mathematically correct. You should consider it as a helpful metaphor, but nothing with direct application.

Comment: So, in what situation would we use Big-O rather than either small-o or theta?

Comment: To denote a tight upper bound. Small-o is at least for practical matters not much more than a toy most often. Quicksort is `o(2^n)`... but what's the use of knowing that? And theta also denotes that `g(n)` is a tight lower bound of `f(n)`, which doesn't necessarily hold if `f(n) = O(g(n))`. It's mostly about the practical usability though.

Comment: f(n) = n if n is odd, 0 if n is even. Then f(n)=O(n), but neither f(n)=Theta(n) nor f(n) = o(n).

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(n)=k!`, when `k` is the smallest integer such that `n<=k!`.

Then `f(n)` is not `θ(n)` (since `f(k!+1)/(k!+1)` tends to infinity) neither is `o(n)` (since `f(k!)=k!`), but clearly `f(n)=O(n)` (as `f(n)<=n`).

Comment: This is a good example, but I think this answer is incomplete. The OP asked "why would we ever use O(...) when θ(...) or o(...) are stronger descriptors?", and although your answer provides *a* reason for that, it's not actually *the* reason for that.